# Natural Deduction Tautology

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I'm trying to prove the following tautologies:

\begin{align}
& ⊢ (A \to (B \to A)) \\
& ⊢ ((A \to B) \to A) \to A
\end{align}

For the first one, what I did was:

1. $A$  assumption

   1. $B$ assumption
   2. $A$ restated
2. $B \to A$  arrow-introduction of 2 and 3

   1. $A \to (B \to A)$  arrow-introduction of 1-4

But this doesn't look right to me.

For the second one, here's what I have so far:

1. ((A --> B) --> A)  assumption

   1. A --> B          assumption
   2. A                arrow-elimination of 1 and 2

Comment: The first one is correct.

Comment: do you know how I would go about doing the second one?

Comment: No, I'm thinking. Tough one!

Comment: I added (above), what I have so far

Comment: What rules do you have at your disposal?

Comment: the normal natural deduction rules - introduction and elimination for: conditionals, conjunctions, disjunctions, negations

Comment: but no _modus tollens_ ($\phi \rightarrow \psi, \lnot\psi \vdash \lnot\phi$) of course?

Comment: oh! yes I can use that

Comment: but how does that help?

Comment: I think I got a proof from scratch. Should I forget about it? Can't be bothered with typing it up if it's not necessary.

Comment: Yeah sure, it'd be interesting to see other approaches

Comment: @user146767 My computer can't read my *Language, Proof and Logic* disc, sorry. If you want it, ping me tomorrow and I'll try in another computer.

Comment: What are your rules for negations?

Answer (score 4):

You'll be starting by assuming $(A\to B)\to A$.

Ideally one would want to prove $A\to B$ and then $A$ would follow, but of course $A\to B$ is not a tautology, so it can't be proven. But $\neg (A\to B)\lor (A\to B)$ is a tautology and therefore it can be proven.

So you'll prove the aforementioned tautology, then you'll perform $\lor\text{-Elim}$ on this tautology.

One of the cases follows from the initial hypothesis.

It remains to be shown that you can prove $A$ from $\neg(A\to B)$.

This goes something like this:

- $\neg (A\to B)$
- $\,\,\,\,\neg A$ (Hypothesis)
- $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, A$ (Hypothesis)
- $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\bot$
- $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \,\,\,\,B$
- $\,\,\,\,A\to B$
- $\,\,\,\, \bot$
- $\neg \neg A$
- $A.$

Comment: I'm not following the ¬(A→B) part.  You show the contradiction, but then you go ahead and use A afterward...

Comment: @user146767 Which line troubles you?

Comment: So I understand the not-A then A hypotheses (though I don't quite see the purpose of that yet), so of course it's a contradiction.  But where does B come from, and how do you get A --> B after?

Comment: Nice. I used contraposition, modus tollens, now you're explicitly appealing to excluded middle. I wonder if the formula we're both trying to prove is intuitionistically valid....If it's not then I wouldn't feel so bad for not being able to come up with a more 'direct' proof (if that makes sense).

Comment: Do you have $\bot\text{-Elim}$?

Comment: @HunanRostomyan I highly doubt it is intuitionistically valid.

Comment: @user146767 Note that I edited my previous comment, it had a typo.

Comment: Which one? I didn't see a response

Comment: @user146767 Click [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774969/natural-deduction-tautology/775061?noredirect=1#comment1608395_775061), (no need to open on new tab).

Comment: oh, the question, I don't know what ⊥-Elim is

Comment: @user146767 See the second proof in my answer.

Comment: @GitGud I can send you the screenshot if you like and remove your proof from my answer. I thought this way would be faster.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan Keep it. Thanks.

Comment: @user146767 I don't think I can save my proof without $\bot\text{-Elim}$. I'll try again tomorrow. I'm off to bed soon.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan I don't think I can use contrapositive either

Comment: @GitGud I can use lemmas as long as I prove them separately as well. Is there a way to prove ⊥-Elim?

Comment: @user146767 $\bot\text{-Elim}$ is a deduction rule and it is not a rule you can prove from the others, I think.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan Peirce's law (what you've tried to prove) is NOT  intuitionistically valid, even though it has NO negations in it at all, and makes NO reference to the law of the excluded middle.  " Examples include not only the law of excluded middle p ∨ ¬p, but also Peirce's law ((p → q) → p) → p, and even double negation elimination."  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic  It follows that the semantics of intuitionistic logic cannot be bivalent.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Ah. That sounds right. I remember reading either Kolmogorov or Glivenko about the unacceptability of (double) negation elimination. I just didn't realize the connection to what you called 'Peirce's law', to our theorem here, until Git Gud produced a proof based on the excluded middle. Apparently they're all connected and intuitionistically unacceptable! Thank you very much for the comment.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan  They aren't all connected.  If you look at the proof of Peirce's law in say a conditional-negation axiomization of classical logic (or even the similarly structure natural deduction system partially outlined in my answer), and forbid inter-definability of connectives as intuitionists do, then a proof of Perice's law says nothing about the law of the excluded middle, which is a disjunction.  On the other hand, if you allow for interdefiniability of connectives, since Cpq:=ANpq, from the weak law of identity Cpp we can obtain ANpp and then ApNp the law of the excluded middle.

Answer (score 3):

You've solved the first, so here are two ways of proving the second one. 'Taut Con' is *modus tollens*.

[image]

I've taken the liberty of typing [Git Gud](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/55235/git-gud)'s alternative proof more explicitly here (please vote his answer up if you too find it insightful). It highlights the connection to the law of excluded middle and is economical in its use of special rules (e.g. doesn't appeal to *modus tollens*). Here it is:

[image]

Another way would be to prove the contrapositive, using just $\rightarrow$-intro & Reit:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I can use step 5...

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Barwise & Etchemendy's _Fitch_ is the proof-checker; the rules are in their book _Language, Proof, and Logic_.

Comment: @user146767 Does the proof by contraposition make sense?

Comment: From step 4, I would just have to show that it means not-B, how would I do that?

Comment: @user146767 In the first proof?

Comment: @user146767: What system are you using?

Comment: from the one we're commenting on...but yeah, I'm not sure how to get to step 5

Comment: @user146767 I've eliminated the appeal to the definition of implication.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan Thanks for typing my proof, though personally I'd prove $\neg(A\to B)\lor (A\to B)\,\,\ddot \smile$

Comment: @HunanRostomyan Where was the part about de morgans law? I might actually be able to use that...

Comment: @user146767 I threw away that proof because it relied on the definition of material implication as a disjunction of a kind. I can look if I have a copy left on my laptop if you want to see that again?

Comment: yes that would be great!

Comment: @user146767 Copy [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ONfYX.png) image before it's deleted (if it ever is):

Comment: Great, thanks! is it step 5 or 6 that is de morgans? (and in that case, what is the other?)

Comment: @user146767 (6), (5) is the definition of $\rightarrow$ step

Answer (score 1):

I use [Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation).  The second formula becomes CCCabaa.  The rule I'll use (other than arrow introduction, which I'll call "Ci", and detachment/conditional elimination, which I'll call "Co") is {CN$\alpha$$\beta$, CN$\alpha$N$\beta$} $\vdash$ $\alpha$, which I'll call "No".

```
hypothesis 1  |     CCaba
hypothesis 2  ||    Na
hypothesis 3  |||   a
hypothesis 4  ||||  Nb
hypothesis 5  ||||| a
Ci 5-5     6  ||||  Caa
Co 6, 3    7  ||||  a
Ci 4-7     8  |||   CNba
hypothesis 9  ||||  Nb
hypothesis 10 ||||| Na
Ci 10-10   11 ||||  CNaNa
Co 11, 2   12 ||||  Na
Ci 9-12    13 |||   CNbNa
No 13, 8   14 |||   b
Ci 3-14    15 ||    Cab
Co 1, 15   16 ||    a
Ci 2-16    17 |     CNaa
hypothesis 18 ||    Na
Ci 18-18   19 |     CNaNa
No 17, 19  20 |     a
Ci 1-20    21       CCCabaa
```

For the first one you could *also* write:

```
hypothesis 1 |   a
hypothesis 2 ||  b
hypothesis 3 ||| a
Ci 3-3     4 ||  Caa
Co 4, 1    5 ||  a
Ci 2-5     6 |   Cba
Ci 1-6     7     CaCba
```

I have to wonder why you didn't also get asked to prove CCpCqrCCpqCpr.  Since you can prove CCpCqrCCpqCpr using only conditional introduction and detachment, 
a consequence here come as that *all* implications (well-formed formulas with *just* "C"'s and variables in them) which qualify as tautologies can get proved from conditional introduction, detachment, and the rule

{CN$\alpha$$\beta$, CN$\alpha$N$\beta$} $\vdash$ $\alpha$, since {CpCqp, CCpCqrCCpqCpr, CCCpqpp} under detachment and uniform substitution comes as sufficient for the implicational propositional calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Pierce's Law:
$$\def\fitch#1#2{~~~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{}{\fitch{~~1.~(A\to B)\to A}{\fitch{~~2.~\neg A}{\fitch{~~3.~A}{~~4.~\bot\hspace{13.5ex}{\neg}\mathsf E~3,2\\~~5.~B\hspace{14ex}\mathsf X~4}\\~~6.~A\to B\hspace{11.5ex}{\to}\mathsf I~3{-}5\\~~7.~A\hspace{17ex}{\to}\mathsf E~6,1\\~~8.~\bot\hspace{17ex}\neg\mathsf E~7,2}\\~~9.~\neg\neg A\hspace{17ex}\neg\mathsf I~2{-}8\\10.~A\hspace{20ex}{\neg\neg}\mathsf E~9}\\11.~((A\to B)\to A)\to A\hspace{3ex}{\to}\mathsf I~1{-}10}$$